# Database.EnsureCreated() fails on foreign key creation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a database on a docker image to use for testing. In my Startup.cs, I added the following:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                using var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
                Application.SetupContext(scope.ServiceProvider);
                using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync().Wait();
                context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync().Wait();
                SqliteDbSeeder.SeedTestDatabase(context);
            }
```

I am getting an exception when it tries to create the Addresses table:

```
Failed executing DbCommand ("18"ms) [Parameters=[""], CommandType='Text',
CommandTimeout='30']"\r\n""CREATE TABLE [Addresses] (\r\n    [Id] int NOT NULL,\r\n  
[CareOf] nvarchar(500) NULL,\r\n    [Address] nvarchar(500) NULL,\r\n    [AptSte] 
nvarchar(255) NULL,\r\n    [City] nvarchar(255) NULL,\r\n    [StateProvince] nvarchar(255) 
NULL,\r\n    [ZipPostalCode] nvarchar(10) NULL,\r\n    [Country] nvarchar(255) NULL,\r\n 
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ContactMechanisms] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),\r\n    CONSTRAINT 
[FK_Addresses_ContactMechanisms_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [ContactMechanisms] 
([Id])\r\n);"
```

`There is already an object named 'PK_dbo.ContactMechanisms' in the database.`

I have a ContactMechanism entity which is extended by a few classes, i.e. PhoneNumber, Address.
EF Core is automatically generating the constraint names but since this key is a constraint on multiple tables it is causing an error.
I tried using
`entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_dbo.Addresses");`, but then it says
'A key cannot be configured on 'Address' because it is a derived type. The key must be configured on the root type 'ContactMechanism'.
I also tried this
`modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().HasBaseType<ContactMechanism>();` but it causes the same original error.

Is there a way to handle this issue, or do I need to set up the database another way?
Note: I did not design this database and the design cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way how EF handles inheritance and PK's in derived entities.

Address is a derived type of ContactMechanism and EF is trying to create a PK for Address that already exists in ContactMechanism.

I believe explicit key configuration is a solution here, by using the FluentApi way through OnModelCreating() method. Explicitly set the keys. See documentation on Fluent Api [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/)

Comment: Did you see that I tried `entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_dbo.Addresses");`? I don't see another solution using FluentApi.

Comment: You don't need to set the PK on the derived type or even use HasBaseType - EF Core will understand that Address uses the same primary key as ContactMechanism. I think it infers it from the class definition

Comment: Well that is not working. Here is the code for the parent type:
`
modelBuilder.Entity<ContactMechanism>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("ContactMechanisms");

                entity.HasKey(e => e.Id)
                    .HasName("PK_dbo.ContactMechanisms");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.ContactMechanismType)
                    .HasDatabaseName("IX_ContactMechanismTypeID");
            });
`